# Turn a Future[Unit] into a Try[Unit] in Scala

Tags: scala, future, akka-persistence

I'm attempting to implement an API method (`AsyncWriteJournal.asyncWriteMessages` – part of Akka 2.4's persistence API) that requires me to return a `Future[Seq[Try[Unit]]]`. The idea being that a number of operations can be performed any of which may individually succeed or fail, the future can be used to await completion of all the operations. The future itself can optionally succeed even there's a certain class of failure in individual operations.

The underlying operations I'm using (Rediscala) return Futures but I'm stuck trying to transform a `Seq[Future[Unit]]` into the required return type. I can do it using `Promise` on each operation and tying them together with `Future.sequence` but then the resulting future fails if *any* of the operations fails which is not the correct behavior

Comment: A future created by `Future.sequence` should not fail just because a `Try` resulted in failure. Can you the code where you assemble the complete future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
def transform(ops: Seq[Future[Unit]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Seq[Try[Unit]]] =
  Future.sequence(ops.map (
    _.map(Success(_)).recover {
      case ex => Failure(ex)
    }
  ))
```

Comment: Yes, that was very helpful. It's not exactly what I've ended up using but the inner map with recover is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about if you turn a possibly failing future into a future that will succeed in any case, and then use `Future.sequence`?

Comment: It's actually more subtle unfortunately (I just updated the question to clarify). Certain classes of failure (serialization) in individual ops can fail their Try but don't _have to_ fail the entire Future. Other classes of failure (failure to write to DB) have to fail the entire thing. I think given that the difference is an optional behavior I'm going to just stick with what I have.

Comment: So you want a failing future to be converted into a Try in some cases, but not in all? `f.map[Try[Unit]](r => Success(())).recover { case c: AcceptableException => Failure(c) }`